# XmlResourceParser: interface implement interface?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html

it said that: `public interface XmlResourceParser implements AttributeSet XmlPullParser.`
As it said, XmlResourceParser is an interface. and interface can't implement interface imo.Only class can do that. Here the ***implement*** should be ***extends***. is the document wrong? or i am wrong ? and where can i see the source code of XmlResourceParser?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/ics/core/java/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.java) for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just an error in documentation. Check [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.java) for example and you'll see that it extends AttributeSet.